# Calculate value of output voltage?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

I tried to solve the question but my answer seems to be different from that in the text( according to which answer is -30 V). please help me solve it.

This is what I did

V+ = V- = -2 V

(-2 - V0)/(8K) = 0.1mA

Thus

V0 = -2.8 V

Comment: Show us what you have done so we can spot the mistake you made  (if any). The book can be wrong as well.

Comment: DC gain of operating amplifiers is very high.  One of the "golden rules" is violated by this circuit.  Are the opamp rails specified as +30/-30V?

Comment: No there are no specifications given. Maybe it is to be assumed.

Comment: I entered the circuit into CircuitLab and did a DC simulation, and it said the output was -2.80v also.

Comment: Can the opamp sink 1.5 mA? (Also, the opamp \$V_+ = -2 \$, not \$+2\$.)

Comment: @copper.hat looks like a typo. His calculation reflects that he used V+ = -2V

Comment: Yes - of course, the ouitput is -2.8 volts (simple superposition at the opamp output).

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is correct. The only assumption we need to start with is that no current flows into either op amp input. That gives a +0.8V difference going from Vo to V- (0.1mA * 8 kΩ).  The difference is fixed by the current source, so when Vo changes, V- changes by the same amount. When Vo = -2.8V, V- = -2.8V + 0.8V = -2V = V+, and the output is stable.

Answer (score 0):

The V+ = V- approximation is valid when the op amp is in closed-loop feedback and not saturated.

I think in this case, the 0.1mA current source is driving the V- node to a different voltage than V+, causing the output to saturate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffFNFk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But the simulation in CircuitLab agrees with the -2.8V answer, assuming that Vn = Vp = -2.0V. This requires that the current source driving the 4k input resistor, is at -1.6V.

It's possible that the author of the textbook made the same assumption I made, that the current source compliance voltage forces the op amp into saturation...